# Finding case sensitive string in a cell from a specific list and return a value from the list

Tags: excel

I am stumped.

I need Excel to search in a cell (Sheet 1, column a) and find a specific string of text from a list (Sheet 2, column a). Then if it finds that specific string of text from the list (Sheet 2, column a), I need it to return the value from the list (Sheet 2, column b) in the cell (Sheet 1, column B).

I appreciate any assistance. Sorry if I am not clear.

- Rico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With error checking and will search the cell for the case-sensitive strings instead of requiring that the cell exactly be a case-sensitive string:

```
=IF(COUNT(INDEX(FIND(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,A1),)),INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,A1)),),0)),"")
```

Comment: +1 tiger, I wasn't sure if a whole cell match was required or a partial one - yours is good for the latter

Comment: Thanks :)  I basically used your formula though, just adjusted it to use `FIND`.  I have given yours +1 also

Comment: `=IF(COUNT(INDEX(FIND(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1),)),INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1)),),0)),"")` to use the columns instead of the first 10 rows.

Comment: I would never recommend using a whole column reference with array-calculated formulas like the one proposed. It can drastically slow down performance.  They should always be limited to just what they need to calculate, or use a dynamic named range instead if you want the data to expand with new entries.

Comment: Perfect. You guys are amazing. I was stumped for hours. Making a spreedsheet for Fantasy Football draft. Thank you again. you guys are true masters.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` are case-sensitive so if you want a case sensitive match try this version

=INDEX(Sheet2!B$1:B$100,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(EXACT(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A$1:A$100),0),0))

`EXACT` is the case-sensitive part.....

Note: I restricted the lookup ranges to 100 rows, expand as required

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- Sheet 1, column a = `Sheet1!A:A`
- Sheet 1, column b = `Sheet1!B:B`
- Sheet 2, column a = `Sheet2!A:A`
- Sheet 2, column b = `Sheet2!B:B`

You can simply insert an `INDEX MATCH` into `Sheet1!B1`

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Comment: Ah, I incorrectly assumed the `0` flag on `MATCH` was `EXACT`. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Most excel functions are not case-sensitive (and nor are "comparison operators" so =EXCEL"="excel" = TRUE). AFAIK the only case-sensitive functions are FIND, EXACT and SUBSTITUTE